# Word like 'agenda' but for an extended period

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anyone know a word like 'agenda', but applying to an extended period of time, like several weeks?

**Edit to explain**

The words 'schedule' and 'calendar' aren't quite the right fit, since I'm looking for something that's not tightly tied to dates... It's for a program that will take place over a course of a few weeks. That said, 'calendar' may work.

Comment: Schedule, calendar? Can you explain what part of "agenda" you're trying to duplicate?

Comment: You might do better with "itinerary."

Comment: You should answer with that, @Oldbag I often here about "itineraries for cruises" or other travel events, generally lasting a week or more.

Comment: In this specific context, an ***agenda*** is more suggestive of a fairly short list of things to be addressed by a single meeting, or by one phase of a larger ***plan***. Going in the opposite direction, a ***strategy*** suggests the possibility of multiple "plans" within a longer-term overall process.

Comment: What's wrong with program/me? [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/programme) **programme**

noun
1.
a planned series of future events or performances.
"a weekly programme of films"
synonyms: schedule, agenda, calendar, timetable ...1.1 A set of related measures or activities with a particular long-term aim:
the British nuclear power programme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer to this is heavily dependent on the type of program that is occurring over time.

If it has anything to do with teaching/learning, **syllabus** is probably the best word, although **curriculum** works just as well.

If it's something that will be happening at different locations **itinerary** is good, although **schedule** or even **timetable** could also fit.

If the multi-date program is a list of speakers/performers/etc. then **lineup** would be appropriate. **Program** would also work especially well in this context, but could really be used for any of these situations.

I also think **agenda** could also work over time, especially with a sentence describing it. i.e., *"The agenda for the next four Wednesdays is...."*